# How to reimplement a QDialog's accept and reject slots?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working on a GUI project where the user is faced with the following QDialog:

```
class StockSelectorDialog(QDialog, stockselector_ui):
    def __init__(self, parent_, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StockSelectorDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, on=True)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.dialogButtonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.dialogButtonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        self.parent_ = parent_
        self.symbolsbuffer = parent_.symbols.copy()

        self.symbolmodel = SymbolListModel(self)
        self.listView.setModel(self.symbolmodel)

        self.symbolAddButton.clicked.connect(self.onAddButtonClicked)
        self.symbolDeleteButton.clicked.connect(self.onDeleteButtonClicked)

    def onAddButtonClicked(self, s):
        symbol = self.symbolEdit.text()
        if symbol:
            self.symbolsbuffer.append(symbol)
            self.symbolmodel.layoutChanged.emit()
            self.symbolEdit.setText("")

    def onDeleteButtonClicked(self, s):
        indexes = self.listView.selectedIndexes()
        if indexes:
            for i in indexes:
                del self.symbolsbuffer[i.row()]

            self.symbolmodel.layoutChanged.emit()
            self.listView.clearSelection()

    def accept(self):
        self.parent_.symbols = self.symbolsbuffer
        self.parent_.onSymbolsChanged()
        self.close()

    def reject(self):
        self.close()
```

The UI file is here: https://github.com/danib-prog/stockmarket-helper/blob/master/stockselector.ui

Everything worked fine until I added the buffer sysytem, for which I had to reimplement the `accept` and the `reject` slots of the dialog (although I'm not very sure about the latter). Now the dialog opens when necessary and the `ListView` works fine with all the buttons and the `LineEdit`, but my `dialogButtonBox` is not responding.

Why is this happening? And what is a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `close()` on a dialog for that, mostly because it causes itself a call to `reject()`; luckily Qt is smart enough to prevent recursion, but the point remains: both those methods are expected to set the dialog's *result* and use `done()`, of `close()`, so that their event loop correctly exits from its `exec_()`.

If you need to override a class function to do something *other than the default behavior*, you should always remember to call the base implementation too in order to correctly achieve the expected result.

```
    def accept(self):
        self.parent_.symbols = self.symbolsbuffer
        self.parent_.onSymbolsChanged()
        super(StockSelectorDialog, self).accept()

    def reject(self):
        super(StockSelectorDialog, self).reject()
```

Also, note that Qt Designer already connects the buttons of a QDialogButtonBox when it's created using the default dialog templates with buttons, so you should not connect them again, otherwise both `accept` and `reject` would be called twice.